# link inside php variable and table

Tags: php, codeigniter, href, html-table

I want to display my data with a link functionality inside the php tag

```
<td><a href ="<? print $row->courier_url;?>"></a></td>
```

this is my code, Its not working.

Comment: Just put some value in `a`, it's working but you can't see it I guess.

Comment: Try `{$row->courier_url};` and check for opening short tags, maybe better `<?=` than `<? print`. Also you need text to be clicked

Comment: "Its not working" Can you please be more descriptive? You should add some text inside the `a` tag, at least.

Comment: Use print_r to check whether key "courier_url" exist or not.

Comment: {$row->courier_url}; is from my database I use foreach($query as $row); Im using eclipse thats why its legal to use short tag like <? ?>. by the way its now working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<td><a href ="<? echo $row->courier_url; ?>"><? echo $row->courier_url; ?> </a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you,

```
<td><a href ="<?=$row->courier_url; ?>"></a></td>
```

Comment: the data did not load on my table, its blank

Answer (score 0):

First off, remove the space between `href =` so it's `href=`. Your php code is actually valid, does `$row->courier_url` actually print anything? How is `$row` being defined?

Also, don't use shorthand `<?` php tags use the full `<?php`. It's bad practice to use the shorthand version.

Comment: I try your first suggestion it did not load my data on my db, the data on $row->courier_url is http:\\Stackoverflow.com. Im using eclipse so its legal to use short tag.

Comment: short tags are legal sure, but it's bad practice. Just because something is supported doesn't mean you should use it. This has more info why you shouldn't use them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use  anyway, glad Marijke's answer helped you out

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<td><a href ="<?=$row->courier_url;?>">Link</a></td>
```

Comment: my link is http://STACKOVERFLOW.COM but why the link go to http://localhost/STACKOVERFLOW.COM ???

Comment: use absolute url not relative like `http://stackoverflow.com` and not `stackoverflow.com` even better, `<td><a href ="http://<?=$row->courier_url;?>">Link</a></td>`

Comment: this `<a href ="http://<?=$row->courier_url;?>">` is changed if that is what you are asking.

Comment: next question sir.. how can I add a scrollbar on my table??

Comment: Put your table in a div and add styling to the div see this [link](http://cssdesk.com/6mmXE)